# Errors with latexmk -c (cleanup) option

Tags: latexmk

I am using latexmk and calling it from within python, with the following command:

```
latex_params = ' -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -gg -silent'
latexmk_string = str("latexmk -cd " + '"' + str(path/filename) + '"' + latex_params)
subprocess.call(latexmk_string, shell=True)
```

Note that the '"' double-quotation marks in the latexmk_string are used in cases where the path name has special characters (such as parenthesis).

The code above works just fine.  The problem I am having is with the -c option to clean up the aux files.  I couldn't find any way to include it in the latex_params string and get it to work.

I was able to get it to work if I used the following code after the code above, essentially calling the cleanup function on its own:

```
subprocess.call('latexmk -c', shell=True)
```

Except, that this ONLY works if the file path is the current directory.  In my case, the .tex file is NOT in the current directory and the -cd option above handles that for the creation of the pdf file.  But then I am not able to get the -c cleanup command to work.

I tried:

```
subprocess.call('latexmk -cd "' + str(path) + '" -c', shell=True)
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

John Collins provided the answer.  The error was that the command to clean up needs to include the .tex filename and not just the path.

Instead of:

```
subprocess.call('latexmk -cd "' + str(path) + '" -c', shell=True)
```

In needs to be:

```
subprocess.call('latexmk -cd "' + str(path/filename) + '" -c', shell=True)
```